# Form with dynamic number of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, dynamic-data, forms

Just thinking about the best way to build an Order form that would (from user-perspective):

- Allow adding multiple items.
- Each item has Name, Job Type drop-down and File upload.
- User can add or remove items.
- User must provide at least one item.
- All the items should be validated (eg: Name, JobType and File are required).
- When he hits the Submit, an Order should be created with all the items in it.

---

So the model looks like: `User -1---*-Order-1---*- OrderItem-*--1-JobType`. Additionally OrderItem includes number of attributes, let's say `name`,  `file`.

---

Now I would like to have as skinny controller as possible. Better with the 'standard' code like:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    if @order.save
      redirect_to account_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not save Order"
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

The most interesting thing is **how a view should look like so that rails automatically binds all the values posted to the correct objects**?

For now I don't worry about degradation from JavaScript, but rather the template for the items to be added and linking all that with the validation (probably as a partial).

I expect a template to look like the one below, but not sure.

```
<input type='text' name='order[order_items[name[]]][]' />
<select name='order[order_items[job_type[]]][]'>...</select>
<input type='file' name='order[order_items[file[]]][]' />
```

I have to clone this template in order to add item using JS.

---

So the answer should:

- Include the view or part of it that demonstrates:

  - correct binding of the post values;
  - correct validation for all items;
- Include related part of model.
- Include changes to the controller IF and ONLY IF necessary.
- (JavaScript is not required)

Ideally I would like to see a sample if somebody knows one (maybe somewhere on GitHub).

And the last note, **please**, check your solutions before posting.

Thanks,
Dmitriy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not answering the question directly, but here are some sources to get you there:

- [Railscasts: Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Railscasts: Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)
- [Railscasts: Complex Forms Part 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3)

On a personal note. Your question comes across as asking for someone to do your work for you. I would gladly post an answer to cover all your needs if I was on the clock.

Comment: Tony, I am sorry for giving the feeling that I want somebody to do the work for me. I haven't had such intention. I just wanted to avoid possible speculations on the answer and just get the clear ones. Such an answer is yours. It is clear as it really provides exact answer I expect - the railcasts 196 (and 197). Thanks a lot.